# Trimming fields when adding documents to Solr

Tags: solr, indexing, trim, dataimporthandler

I'm using the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) from Solr to index certain data from a database. However, the database table scheme uses `CHAR`-fields, so they have a fixed width and have some trailing spaces.

I'm trying to remove these trailing spaces (trimming them) by using the `solr.TrimFilterFactory`.
In my Solr `schema.xml` I'm using the following field type to index the data:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" updateOffsets="true" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

So now I'm adding a document like:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="test">Test       </field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

And I'm expecting that the trailing spaces from the test-field are removed, but when I query for: `test:Test*`, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="test">Test       </str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

So as you can see, the trailing spaces are not removed. I must be doing something wrong or misunderstood the concept of filters. But my **expectation** was that the query would return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="test">Test</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

So my question is how I can make sure that when indexing these documents, all trailing spaces get removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr analyzers/filters do not modify the stored value.
Only the indexed value would be modified.
So the `TrimFilterFactory` does not change the stored value and would return the same value as input.

If using DIH, Check [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to modify the value before it is fed to Solr.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The ScriptTransformer is indeed doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of solr, you can use the `TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory`

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="skip-empty" default="true">

   <processor class="TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" /> 

   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />    
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am elaborating this solution based on Solr 8.4 above and latest version. They made is very easy to implement.

I had same problem that most of my fields had trailing spaces and I have many many fields like that in millions of data docs.

I added below line in **SolrConfig.xml**
Search for existing below tag and add TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory like below. one line only.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain .....>
  <processor class="TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />

</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Hope that make easy.